# Weekly Average Starting on Different Days - postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to calculate the weekly average of app usage duration (each usage has it's own log with the duration). 
The problem is that I would like to compare the averages before one certain event took place and after (different date for each user). So if the event took place on Tuesday one month ago, I would like to calculate weekly averages starting on Tuesdays before that specific Tuesday and after.

Relevant data look as follows:
EVENTS

```
User ID || date of event
3fin2d..|| 19/03/17
2f4j34..|| 20/03/17
```

USAGE

```
UID      || timestamp start   ||  timestamp end      || Duration
3fin2d.. || 11/03/17 11:20:00 ||  11/03/17 12:00:00  ||   00:40
3fin2d.. || 18/03/17 11:20:00 ||  18/03/17 12:00:00  ||   00:40
2f4j34.. || 19/03/17 18:20:00 ||  19/03/17 18:40:00  ||   00:20
2f4j34.. || 19/03/17 19:20:00 ||  19/03/17 20:00:00  ||   00:40
3fin2d.. || 19/03/17 19:30:00 ||  19/03/17 20:00:00  ||   00:30
2f4j34.. || 20/03/17 19:20:00 ||  20/03/17 20:00:00  ||   00:40
```

edit: 
USERS

```
UID        || Created On
3fin2d..   || 11/03/17 11:00:00
2f4j34..   || 18/03/17 13:00:00
```

Expected Result:

```
UID      ||Average Duration before even||Average Duration After event 
3fin2d.. ||            00:40:00        ||    00:30:00
2f4j34.. ||            01:00:00        ||    00:40:00
```

of course weeks with 0 usage should be considered. 
In the above example I assume current date is 20/03/17 (otherwise many more zeros should be counted).

Thank you

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: With that table data, what's the expected result? And show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Show desired output.

Comment: Done. I don't have a normal looking attempt. I'm not sure how to handle the dates so all I have is the selected columns

Answer (score 0):

http://rextester.com/USBJ20378

```
select uid,
    avg(u.duration) filter (where usage_start < e.event_date) as before,
    avg(U.duration) filter (where usage_start >= e.event_date) as after
from
    usage u
    inner join
    events e using (uid)
where usage_start between e.event_date - 7 and e.event_date + 7
group by uid
;
  uid   |  before  |  after   
--------+----------+----------
 2f4j34 | 00:30:00 | 00:40:00
 3fin2d | 00:40:00 | 00:30:00
```

Comment: Thanks! But I think perhaps I was unclear. What you provided returns the numbers of only 1 week before and 1 week after. 
I need the average of all weeks before and of all weeks after..